# Need with Javascript function for Select check

Tags: javascript

I tried to create a function to check on a drop-down option on select box. It requires a user to select a user name before submit. I put '0' and check if this = 0, then return false, but it didn't work.

I added a function to check radio buttons and they all worked fine. However, the select Staff doesn't work. I mean, when I click on Submit after checking all radio boxes, it get submitted anyway. How do I fix it to make it work?

Can you help me?

```
<script language="javascript">
function validateForm(daForm) {
nCount = document.frmReport.txtCount.value;
    // check all rb radio buttons
    for (var i = 1; i < nCount; i++) {
        if (! getCheckedRadioValue(daForm["Report"+i])) {
            alert ("Please select a value for option " + i)
            return false
         }
if (UserID.options[UserID.selectedIndex].value == 0) {
                alert("Please select a user");
                return false
    }
    // add other checks here...
                alert ("Thank you!")
                window.open("Search.asp")
    return true
}
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="newMenu" name="frmReport" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
    <select name="UserID">
          <option value=0>Staff name:</option>
          <option value=1>Jenny</option>
          <option value=2>David</option>
     </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like something is wrong with the selector.

Comparing against a "0" value seems to work just fine. I've included a snippet which shows this.

***In short, change this...***

```
if (UserID.options[UserID.selectedIndex].value == 0) {
     alert("Please select a staff");
     return false
}
```

***To this***

```
if (document.querySelector("[name='UserID']").value == 0) {
     alert("Please select a staff");
     return false
}
```

Make multiple selections and submit to see the results.

```js
function validateForm(daForm){
  var select = document.querySelector("[name='UserID']")
  
  if(select.value == 0){
    console.log("Please select a value");
  }else{
    console.log("Selection made.");
  }

  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="newMenu" name="frmReport" onSubmit="return validateForm(this)">
    <select name="UserID">
          <option value=0>Staff name:</option>
          <option value=1>Jenny</option>
          <option value=2>David</option>
     </select>
     
     <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just use `UserID` and work on it with JavaScript. That is the name of the select element. What you need to do is to select it using JavaScript and then work with it.

```
var UserID = document.getElementsByName("UserID")[0];
if (UserID.options[UserID.selectedIndex].value == 0) {
                alert("Please select a staff");
                return false
    }
    // add other checks here...
                alert ("Thank you!")
    return true;
}
```

[<== Fiddle Me ==>](https://jsfiddle.net/ttquzb3b/)